# How many views can be added in a UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subviews

I want to know, A single `UIViewController` can have Max of views inside `UIViewController`. Even I have gone through in iOS Developer Forum, I haven't got answer for that.

Comment: No limitation about that.

Answer (score 2):

**There are no limitation for this**, but its up to you that how exactly you need it, and how properly you're using it? In some cases, when you need multiple tableviews in your controller, its up to you that if you can manage it with a single table or would take more tables for this.

Answer (score 0):

**No limit** but you have to manage properly.

please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html)

Thank you